# Node.js - How to Call External Function from AWS Lambda Index.js

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I am very new to AWS Lambda and Node.js, so apologies for the elementary question. I have two JS files in my Lambda project's root directory:

**index.js**

```
engageMessage(); //For testing purposes - throws error

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // TODO implement
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('This is index'),
    };
    return response;
};
```

**messenger.js**

```
function engageMessage() {
    console.log("Messenger, checking in!");
};
```

How do I call engageMessage() from my index.js file? Each time I try, I get a "TypeError: engageMessage is not a function" message, and am unsure of how to properly reference/import/require messenger.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In messenger.js you need to export your function

```
module.exports = { engageMessage }
```

Then require it in your index.js

```
const { engageMessage } = require("./messenger.js")
```